# How do I provide files for download?

Tags: jekyll

I have written a post and would like to provide a file as attachment for download.

So far I have

- created a link `[Download files][download-file]`
- declared the link as `[download-file]: download.zip`
- put `download.zip` in the `_posts` folder

However, the file does not get copied to the correct location.

I have

- read about [data files](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/)
- read about [directory structure](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/)
- read about [static files](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/), which IMHO was the closest hit. Unfortunately, no example is provided.

So neither page gave me an answer on how to provide files for download.

I don't know where to put static files in the directory structure. Once I knew that, it seems I could use some Liquid like `{{ site.static_files }}`, but even then I'd still need to specify a file name.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is my solution. I have a "myname".github.io, I created a folder `/download` inside the `myname.github.io` and inside this `download` folder I uploaded the files I want to include in my posts.

In the single post then I created the following code:

```
some text and [here is possible to download the file in PDF][1]

[1]:{{ site.url }}/download/file.pdf
```

Comment: I see how this could work on Github or anywhere else after copying the site to another webserver. If possible, I'd like to be able to test my site locally during `jekyll serve`. Adding a download folder into `_site` always gets deleted.

Comment: Doing this also works locally. Just place the `download` folder on top level. `jekyll serve` will copy it into `_site`. For the URL, I just use `/download/file.ext`.

Comment: The url for the working example has rotted away, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You can place your `download.zip` file in the root of your project, and it will get copied over to `{{ site.url }}/download.zip`. If you'd like it contained in a folder, you can create any folder, eg `download/`, and any file will be able to accessed via `{{ site.url }}/download/*`.

> Every other directory and file except for [the Jekyll files]—such as css and images folders,  favicon.ico files, and so forth—will be copied verbatim to the generated site.

from [the Jekyll Docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/)

Comment: How is this answer different from the existing answer?

Comment: I tried editing the existing answer to add the reference/explanation, and it was rejected :/ just putting the info out there for anyone else that was looking for a more thorough explanation of the behavior or Jekyll doc reference (I was). The link in @SabDeM's answer was dead, too.

Comment: With your current reputation on Stack Overflow, your edit is placed into a review queue. It has better chances to be accepted if a) the edit is as small as possible b) you describe why you changed something in the edit comment. A dead link is IMHO a good reason for editing. I can't tell why exactly your edit was rejected. Thanks for the explanation.